# React, map com 2 json sem id

Tags: react

Gostaria de uma ajuda: Tenho dois Json: posts e author. O Json posts não tem id.
OJson retorna certinho no log. Já tenho o componente card criado, mas não consigo renderizar os posts na tela. Cada post tem um respectivo autor.
GRato

JSONs :
Publicações: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5be5e3fa2f000082000fc3f8
Autores: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5be5e3ae2f00005b000fc3f6

App.js:

````
import Routes from './routes';
import api from '../src/services/api';

import Navbar from '../src/components/Navbar';
import PostCard from '../src/components/PostCard';

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadPosts() {
      const response = await api.get('5be5e3fa2f000082000fc3f8')
      const { postsApi } = await response.data

      console.log(response.data);

      setPosts(postsApi);
    }
    loadPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <div id="App">
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <section className="cards">
        {posts?.map((post, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <PostCard post={post} ></PostCard>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App; ```
````

Comment: E qual o problema? A `key` com base no `index`?

Comment: Não renderiza os posts na tela..

Comment: Ah, sim... Está escrito na pergunta mas me passou batido. Com a sintaxe `posts.map` (removendo a interrogação `?`) funciona? Conheço essa sintaxe em **Kotlin** mas nunca vi em **React**...

Comment: Hum.Não funciona. Não reconhece a function map se tirar o ?

Comment: Se você colocar um `console.log(posts)` antes do `return`, o que aparece no console? [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/446218/edit) a pergunta com essa informação.

Comment: Retorna certinho. Como no link

Comment: **Se** a variável `posts` estiver com o valor correto (contendo um array), `posts.map` **deve** funcionar. Se você colocar, dentro do `map`, apenas tags `p`, por exemplo `<p>Teste</p>`, ele continua sem exibir nada?

Comment: Ainda continua.

Comment: a sua duvida é como unir esse dois resultados?

Comment: Isso, unir os dois

Comment: Então mude a pergunta e coloque como eu faço a união que pelo que eu pude entender você já consegue resgatar os dois json.

Comment: Estava dando erro, mas foi solucionado.. Mas a segunda etapa seria juntar os dois JSON, isso que falta ainda..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando melhor o seu código percebi que o erro se encontra na linha `const { postsApi } = await response.data`

### Problemas:

**`console.log`**

Você diz que o `console.log` retorna o JSON correto, porém você chama `console.log(response.data)` e não `console.log(postsApi)`, que é onde você está armazenando os dados desejados. Consequentemente, você **não sabe** se a variável `postsApi` está com os dados corretos.

**`await response.data`**

Isso não faz sentido. Você usou `await` no `api.get`, que é assíncrono, não precisa usar `await` para ler um atributo de um objeto.

**`const { postsApi } = await response.data`**

Por último (e a raíz da sua pergunta), removendo o `await`, temos `const { postsApi } = response.data`. Isso é o mesmo que `const postsApi = response.data.postsApi`, consegue ver o erro agora? O objeto `response.data` não possui um atributo `postsApi`.

### Solução

Como dito no parágrafo anterior, você precisa apenas corrigir o modo de armazenar os dados obtidos da api. Se você não entender direito como funciona o seu código anterior, leia sobre [Atribuição via desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao).

```
const postsApi = response.data
```

Comment: Puts!!! Não acredito..kk
Verdade..
Mas agora pra pegar o autor do outro Json?

Comment: Faça um procedimento similar ao que você fez para obter os posts e armazene do jeito que faz sentido na sua aplicação. Por exemplo, Após pegar o `postsApi`, você obtém os autores (com um request) e faz um mapeamento para associar os posts aos autores corretos.